# Overriding Django RelatedManager and Queryset to filter on a field in the Through Model

Tags: python, django, django-orm, django-related-manager

I have two models that are linked via Many-To-Many field via third Through Model. The Through Model has some extra fields in it. I want to override the RelatedManager to produce some custom QuerySets that use the extra fields in the Through Model. The caveat is that my Through Model is created using a subclass/mixin that defines the extra fields. What I want to be able to do is get all the Gene objects related to the SampleBatch that have an active status of 1 in the SampleBatchGene instances linking the Many-to-Many fields:

```
In [1]: SampleBatch.objects.get(sample__lab_number="18_11998").genes.active()                                                                                                        
Out[1]: <QuerySet [<Gene: BAP1>]>
```

This is what I have so far:

```
class SampleBatch(models.Model):
    sample = models.ForeignKey(Sample, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    batch = models.ForeignKey(Batch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    genes = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Gene", through='SampleBatchGene', related_name='samplebatches',
        blank=True, through_fields=('samplebatch', 'gene')
    )

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'sample_batch'
        unique_together = (('sample', 'batch'),)
        verbose_name_plural = "Sample batches"

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.sample, self.batch)


class Gene(models.Model):
    gene_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    gene_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255, db_index=True)
    hgnc_number = models.IntegerField(unique=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'gene'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.gene_name


class ActiveQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def active(self):
        return self.filter(active=1)

    def inactive(self):
        return self.filter(active=0)

class LinkMixin(models.Model):
    ACTIVE_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Inactive'),
        (1, 'Active')
    )

    activated = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    active = models.IntegerField(
        choices=ACTIVE_CHOICES, default=1, db_index=True
    )
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    deactivated = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    objects = models.Manager()
    statuses = ActiveQuerySet.as_manager()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class SampleBatchGene(LinkMixin):
    samplebatch = models.ForeignKey(SampleBatch, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gene = models.ForeignKey(Gene, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'sample_batch_gene'
        unique_together = (('samplebatch', 'gene'), )

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}-{}'.format(self.samplebatch, self.gene)
```

Trying to use a custom reverse manager ([as per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)) gives the following error:

```
In [5]: SampleBatch.objects.get(sample__lab_number="18_11998").genes.all()                                                                                                                                    
Out[5]: <QuerySet [<Gene: BAP1>]>

In [6]: SampleBatch.objects.get(sample__lab_number="18_11998").genes.filter(samplebatchgene__active=1)                                                                                                        
Out[6]: <QuerySet [<Gene: BAP1>]>

In [7]: SampleBatch.objects.get(sample__lab_number="18_11998").genes(manager="statuses").active()                                                                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d8d95f5854b4> in <module>
----> 1 SampleBatch.objects.get(sample__lab_number="18_11998").genes(manager="statuses").active()

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.6/envs/varDB/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py in __call__(self, manager)
    848 
    849         def __call__(self, *, manager):
--> 850             manager = getattr(self.model, manager)
    851             manager_class = create_forward_many_to_many_manager(manager.__class__, rel, reverse)
    852             return manager_class(instance=self.instance)

AttributeError: type object 'Gene' has no attribute 'statuses'
```

EDIT: Prompted by Willem Van Onsem: It's trying to use a custom manager from `Gene`, but I've defined it against `SampleBatchGene`. So I need work out how to specify the custom manager from the Through Model. I had hoped to make this work via the `LinkMixin` so I wouldn't have to define the custom manager on both models at either end of the `Many-To-Many`. I guess I could stick the custom manager on both `SampleBatch` and `Gene` and have it work, but I've got a lot of this type of relationship that uses the `LinkMixin` as a Through Model so was hoping to avoid it somehow.

Comment: Where did you define a custom manager in the `Gene` model?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes good spot. See my edit for an update. :)